# what is the use of resolveMandatoryClass(String name) in Interface ClassResolver of Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to camel and While reading some code , I found these linesof codes,

```
String className = "ConvertMapToBeanType";
Class clazz = exchange.getContext().getClassResolver().resolveMandatoryClass(className);
```

`getContext()` returns CamelContext.

`getClassResolver()` Returns the class resolver to be used for loading/lookup of classes.

And what `resolveMandatoryClass(className)` do? Is this returns Object of the 'className' Class. Is this true, then what is the advantage of creating class like this?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your runtime environment or configuration you might want to apply different [strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) how to load a class by name. The calling code does not care about the strategy as long as it is the right one for the environment. So you provide an interface (e.g., `ClassResolver`) to the calling code to execute one of several different strategy implementations (e.g., `DefaultClassResolver` and `OsgiClassResolver`) to achieve the goal.